# how to set background image to PDF page using iText?

Tags: android, itext

I am using `iText` for creating `pdf`, i need to set background image to first `pdf`  page but image is high resolution, how can set background image with out reduce image quality. Please help me.

Comment: The question probably doesn't get an answer because it isn't clear what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

there is work around for doing this by setting the image at absolute position and setting the page size equal to background image and don't forget to put the image in proper dpi folder :)

```
private void setBackground(Document document) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.background_img);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, stream);
    Image img;
    try {
        img = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

        document.add(img);
    } catch (BadElementException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```